# Fb Accountkit SMS Authentication with AWS lambda

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, account-kit

I'm working on a product(web+app) where I need to provide 3 ways to login:(No signup for the user)
1. FB
2. Gmail
3. SMS Login(FB accountkit).

We are using AWS lambda and API gateway for delivering our content to the frontend. I'm a little confused on how to go about integrating the above login methods in AWS. I read on AWS cognito but I don't think it will integrate with FB accountkit(SMS Login). Could anybody please throw some light here ?

Comment: https://github.com/floodfx/react-account-kit-web

Answer (score 0):

Did you try check if the Access token from account kit has the same structure than fb login access token?, if so you can use the same method than facebook login on cognito and add login with that token...